# Set Matlab's Contour graph x-axis scale?

Tags: matlab, contour

I am trying to graph a contour graph with a two dimentional matrix, `v`. v contains velocity data, y-index represents depth, x-index is mapped to a 1d-vector containing latitude info, `lat`.

when I graph `contour(v)`, the x-axis is index, but I wish to show the latitude (also scale accordingly), I tried contour(lat,v) but it just shows me a blank graph, how should I graph it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having an example dataset, it's hard to say for sure... but I suspect that what you need to do is use the `contour(X,Y,Z)` form of `contour`.  If you want to specify one axis, you need to specify both.  In your case, it would be:

```
contour(lat,depth,v)
```

If you're happy using the y-index rather than an actual depth vector, you can do

```
contour(lat,1:size(v,2),v)
```